# Hardcode Frequency of .csv write in python

Tags: python, airsim

So I am running AirSim and I have an API that gathers data and writes it to a file. I want to limit the frequency of the write speed to 60 Hz (or write 60 times every second). How would I do this. Currently I just have the write command in a while loop.

while True:

```
gps_data = client.getGpsData().gnss.geo_point
alt = (gps_data.altitude)
lat = (gps_data.latitude)
lon = (gps_data.longitude)
gps_data_struct = [lat,lon,alt]

with open(output_file,'a') as gpscsvfile:
   gpscsvwriter = csv.writer(gpscsvfile)
   gpscsvwriter = gpscsvwriter.writerow(gps_data_struct)    



#print("Altitude: %s\nLatitude %s\nLongitude %s" %(alt,lat,lon) )
if False:
  break
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this assumes that all the code inside the `while True` takes less than 1 second to run right? If the code ends up taking longer than 1 second then the code below ends up running the code every "whole second" value after the last run. i.e. if the first run starts at `0` and takes `1.1` seconds, then the second run will start at `2`.

```
import time
starttime = time.time()
while True:
    gps_data = client.getGpsData().gnss.geo_point
    alt = gps_data.altitude
    lat = gps_data.latitude
    lon = gps_data.longitude
    gps_data_struct = [lat, lon, alt]

    with open(output_file,'a') as gpscsvfile:
        gpscsvwriter = csv.writer(gpscsvfile)
        gpscsvwriter = gpscsvwriter.writerow(gps_data_struct)
    
    time.sleep(1 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 1))
```

If you need something more robust you could look at [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)